# How to host custom Web Service in Dynamic CRM 4.0

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

**Desired Outcome:**
Expose my own Web Service in Dynamic CRM 4.0 (IFD), and accessible by external application

e.g.

*CRM Web Server URL*: https://Org.CrmServer.com/

*CRM Web Service URL*: https://Org.CrmServer.com/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmService.asmx

*My own Web Service URL*: https://Org.CrmServer.com/MyServices/Dummy.asmx

**Problem Encountered:**

1. By accessing my Service URL in the
   browser, it redirects me to the sign
   in page. I entered a valid
   credential, and then it redirects me back
   to the Service Description page. So
   far so good
2. In my external application (C#),
   I've added Web Service Reference,
   and tried to call my Web Service by

   `MyService.Dummy d = new MyService.Dummy();`

   `string s = d.HelloWorld();`
3. The code above throws exception with
   error message (a HTML doc with
   "Object Moved" to CRM sign in
   page. (It's like what I see in the browser, redirecting to sign in page)
4. Modified code to pass in the credential but still doesn't work

   `MyService.Dummy d = new MyService.Dummy();`

   `d.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");`

   `string s = d.HelloWorld();`

**Questions:**

- Have I hosted my Web Service in the
  correct manner? If not, what's the
  correct way of doing it?
- How to I consume my Web Service
  without being redirected to sign in
  page?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you working in On-Premise or IFD?

Comment: it's IFD, updating the question now

Answer (score 0):

I've hosted web services inside the CRM Website. But to do this, I put them in the ISV folder. Therefore my service urls look something like

```
https://CrmServer.com/ISV/MyServices/Dummy.asmx
```

You could try doing it this way. I have assumed you are doing this on an IFD.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however even putting the Web Service under ISV folder, the first page is still hitting sign in page

Comment: Have you tried including the orgname in the url? ie. https: //myOrg.CrmServer.com/ISV/MyServices/Dummy.asmx

Comment: Yes, Org name is included, I should be more specific in the question.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is whether or not you need a domain name in your network credential.